# PHP preg_grep and accented characters

Tags: php, regex

It is possible to make search with preg_grep that finds words with/without accents ? I found this example, I tested and it not works :

```
$dictionary = array('nestlé');
$pattern = '/^nestle/ui';

$result = preg_grep ( $pattern, $dictionary );

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: No, it is not the same question.

Comment: I believe you would need to create a map of all accented characters and their associated base latin characters and then run a `preg_replace_callback` calling this mapping function.

Comment: @DayronGallardo I believe it's very similar, in fact take a look at this regexp using the pattern from the answer in that question: https://xrg.es/#1vsefc0